# How can I visualise Egos with no connections for my sociocentric network?

Tags: r

I have Interview data from a sociocentric network asking people (n=50) about their connections within the network. 2 people have no connections. How can I achieve that those people are shown as "lone" dots without any arrows in my visual network? So far I have connected them with themselves (so the Alter for Ego1 is Ego1)
Here is my code so far:
`###Sociocentric network with boundaries###

```
library("igraph")
BoundaryData = read.csv("Data_Boundaries.csv", sep=';')
BoundaryData <- as.matrix(BoundaryData)
Network_Closed <- graph.edgelist(BoundaryData, directed=TRUE)
#Visualize Netzwerk
plot(Network_Closed, vertex.size = 8, vertex.label.cex = .7)
#igraph2
source("igraphplot2.R")
environment(plot.igraph2) <- asNamespace('igraph')
environment(igraph.Arrows2) <- asNamespace('igraph')
plot(Network_Closed, vertex.size = 8, edge.arrow.size = .3,edge.arrow.width = 1, vertex.label.cex = .7)
```

#End`

BoundaryData is my excel frame with Row A for Egos and Row B for ALters. I have also added attributes and colours for them but I don't think that's relevant at this point.

Many thanks in advance for your help
MA from Germany
PS: I´m quite new to network visualisation so please be kind and explain your solutions for a newbie

Comment: A colleague helped me find a solution: Network_new <- simplify(Network_Closed,
  remove.loops = TRUE,
)